# watch em um ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho a seguinte input:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Publish" 
 ng-click="submit(editAddNotification)" project-focus-invalid-field>
```

Quando o executo ele faz a inserção da alteração no meu banco de dados (um PUT).

Porém estou precisando que no momento que o concluir o PUT ele chame uma determinada função que está em outro controller.

Queria saber se existe uma possibilidade de usar o $watch no ng-click pra quando ele disparar chamar essa função que criei

```
scope.enableEdit = function() {
                    showAction([
                        'editNavItem',
                        'addNavItem',
                        'editNavItemContent'
                    ]);
                };
```

O problema acontece por que quando ele adiciona algo no database ele faz um reset nos parametros do input.

Comment: Não seria o caso de um service onde você centraliza o processo de inserção e notificação?

Comment: @OnoSendai boa, eu realmente pensei nisso como peguei o projeto desta forma e o meu cliente tem uma certa 'pressa' eu precisaria de uma solução com a estrutura atual.
Mas você tem toda razão aliás vou tentar colocar uma flag no serviço que ele retorna.

Comment: Eu lamento. =/ Maneira suja e rápida - injete RootScope, utilize `broadcast` para anunciar o update e monitore, no seu outro controle, o evento.

Comment: Sample - `$rootScope.$broadcast('nomeDoEvento')`. Para monitorar o evento, use `$rootScope.$on('nomeDoEvento', function () {...});`

Comment: Realmente vai ficar um pouco sujo, mas vou tentar aqui para deixar funcionando e vou seguir sua sugestão com o lance do serviço.

Comment: Se funcionar, adicione sua própria resposta demonstrando como você implementou. Eu não fiz mais do que comentar. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de verificar várias opções, decidi usar o $broadcast, porém como o @OnoSendai falou ficaria algo muito sujo, para não ficar tão sujo assim criei um serviço para o broadcast, desta forma sempre quando eu quiser chamar o `$rooscope.$broadcast` ou o `$rootScope.$on` eu apenas instâncio meu serviço e faço da utilização dele. Vocês podem conferir o código aqui, basicamente criei um pubSub com um `pubSub.dispath`e um `pubSub.addListener` entendam o primeiro como o que vai ficar olhando e caso modificado vai avisar para o segundo que algo ali aconteceu.

Não irei postar o código aqui por que ficaria muito longo, mas quem tiver interesse no mesmo aqui tenho um **[gist](https://gist.github.com/devedmo/f852c629c0c713b211e0)** que contém o serviço "broadcast" e quem tiver alguma melhoria ou dúvida fico a disposição. Agradeço a todos.